# filterWidgetOptions Doesn't work (yii2)

Tags: gridview, yii2

On the kartik gridview i want to add filter with select 2 type like below:

```
[
                'attribute' => 'product_id',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                return $model->product->name;
                },
                'filterType'=>GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
                'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\ProductWord::find()->asArray()->all(), 'name', 'name'),
                'filterWidgetOptions'=>[
                    'pluginOptions'=>['allowClear'=>true, 'minimuminputLength' => 3],
                ],
                'filterInputOptions'=>['placeholder'=>'Any Product', 'multiple' => true ],
                'group'=>true,  // enable grouping
                'label' => 'Product',
                 'headerOptions' =>
                     ['style'=>'max-width: 70%; font-size: 12px;overflow: auto; word-wrap: break-word;'],
                'contentOptions' =>
                    ['style'=>'max-width: 70%; font-size: 12px;overflow: auto; word-wrap: break-word;'],
],
```

but the result is `filterWidgetOptions` doesn't work. I add `allowclear` and `minimuminputLength` but it doesn't work. what i do wrong wih this code ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Since search model looks for id to make a search, you should map

> id

to

> name

```
 'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\ProductWord::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
```

Also, change your  **value**  like below.  You should use your model to get values.

```
'value' => function ($model) {
        return $model->product->name;
     },
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct is:

```
minimumInputLength => 3
```

it is works!